# Core Data multithreading--what am I doing wrong

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'll try to keep this brief but basically, I have an app that, in a certain mode, can near-continuously log location and other data, and snap photos (using AVFoundation) and store it all in Core Data. I discovered, as suspected, that all of this would need to be threaded...otherwise the UI gets extremely sluggish.

I have never attempted to combine Core Data with concurrency before so I read up on it as best I could. I feel like I understand what I'm supposed to do, but for someone reason it's not right. I crash with this error: "Illegal attempt to establish relationship "managedDataPoint" between objects in different contexts. I know what this means, but I thought what I have below would avoid this (I'm following what I've read)...since I get an Object ID reference from the main context, and use that to grab a new reference to the object and pass it to the "temp" context...but that isn't working as Core Data still claims I'm attempting to create a relationship across contexts (where?). Appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
-(void)snapPhotoForPoint:(ManagedDataPoint*)point
{

if (!_imageCapturer)
{
    _imageCapturer = [[ImageCapturer alloc] init];
}

if (!_tempContext) {
    _tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    _tempContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}

__block NSManagedObjectID* pointID = [point objectID];

[_tempContext performBlock:^{

    NSError *error = nil;

    Photo *newPhoto = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:_tempContext];
    UIImage *image = [_imageCapturer takePhoto];
    newPhoto.photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    ManagedDataPoint *tempPoint = (ManagedDataPoint*)[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:pointID];
    newPhoto.managedDataPoint = tempPoint; // *** This is where I crash

    if (![_tempContext save:&error]) { // I never get here.
        DLog(@"*** ERROR saving temp context: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
ManagedDataPoint *tempPoint = (ManagedDataPoint*)[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:pointID];
```

not be

```
 ManagedDataPoint *tempPoint = (ManagedDataPoint*)[_tempContext objectWithID:pointID];
```

Otherwise you are working with different contexts! Also you should check if objectID is a temporary ID and acquire a "final" one in case of.

Comment: But the object I need is in the main context! It's passed-in at the top of the method. I guess maybe I'm just not understanding this correctly? If the object I need was created and exists in the main context, how can I retrieve if from my "temp" context? I don't think it will be there unless I had already saved and pushed from main to temp...and I'm trying to go the other way (from temp to main).

Comment: you are using the objectID and get the point object from the _tempContext so you can establish a relationship within the same context. Exactly as you described yourself and as it is documented.

Comment: Well...I gave it a whirl and I'm at least not crashing anymore. Don't know if it's "working" per se as I haven't tested. Thanks very much for the info...I'm still struggling to understand, though. If I use an object ID for a an object in one context, and then query another context using that ID, and that object doesn't exist in the second context, does it just fault and create one for me since the two contexts share a persistent store?

Comment: Before 10.7 one had to use NSManagedObjectContectDidSave notifications and such to keep in sync. Yet with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType it is not necessary anymore.

Comment: If it is working you may mark it checked so others know they find an answer here

Comment: Works indeed, thanks very much, and now I think I understand...if the two contexts share the same persistent store (and same persistent store coordinator) and I "ask" one context for an object created in the other, by way of the object ID, it will fault and create it there. Is that right?